# LinuxサーバのOS選択画面について

Tags: linux

こんにちは。

先日、運用しているLinuxサーバについて、電源工事のため電源をオフし、再度スイッチを入れたところ、それまでなかった「OSの選択画面」が表示されました。（表示されたのは、現在使用しているCentOSのバージョン（6.5）と、もうひとつのLinuxのバージョン（いくつか、は覚えていません。ごめんなさい。）でした。
前回の電源オフ－＞起動時には「OSの選択画面」が表示されていなかったため、運用手順と異なるということで、調査することになりました。
ただ、前回の電源オフ時から今回の電源オフ時にOSを入れなおしたり、手動でバージョンアップを行ったりしたことはありませんので、どこから調べたらよいかわからず困っています。
（Apacheの設定変更や、Tomcatの設定変更は行っていますが、それが影響しているとは思えず・・）
CentOSのyum等による自動バージョンアップなどが起因することもあるのかと思い、yum-cromが設定されていないか、yum.logにログが出力されていないか、などの切り口は確認してみましたがyum-cronは設定されておらず、また、yum.logは空で、自動でバージョンアップがされた形式は見当たりませんでした。（探し方が悪い可能性もありますので、その点ご指摘いただければと思います。）

何か手掛かりやヒントがありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/boot/grub/grub.confのhiddenmenuが外されたってこと？
ファイルの変更日からその日に何があったか知らべてみるとか。普通はさわらないファイルだし。
もし操作ログをきちんととっているなら誰かがいじってるのがわかるんじゃない？

Comment: ありがとうございます。このファイルの存在自体を知りませんでした。早速ファイルを見てみたところ、2つのOSが記載されていました。ただ、このファイルの日付がだいぶ古いことから、
「もともとOSが2つインストールされていて、かつ、前回起動時にはOSの選択画面を見逃した」可能性がありますね・・。
一度関係者に確認してみます。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 自動バージョンアップで、新しいカーネルがインストールされることで、 grub.conf に複数のカーネルがインストールされることはあり得ます。 `rpm -q kernel` を実行して、複数のバージョンが表示されるなら複数のカーネルがインストールされています。(まだ本題に入れていないのですが、長くなったので別コメントで続きを書きます)

Comment: (続き) とはいえ、複数のカーネルがインストールされても、回答にある `hiddenmenu` が消されたりはしません。まずはこれが記述されているか確認するとよいでしょう。もし記述されていたら、OS起動中にうっかりキーボードに触れたのではないでしょうか。CentOSでは、普通、数秒キーボード入力を待って、入力がなければ、規定のカーネルで起動しますが、入力があると選択メニューが表示されます。

Comment: ｺﾒﾝﾄ追記ありがとうございます。確認したところ、やはり、過去にバージョンアップをしていたことが分かりました。grub.confには複数のカーネルバージョンが記載されていました。また、端末の起動を操作した人は、統合コンソールにて、キーボード操作でサーバを切替ながら複数のサーバの状態を見ていたとのことでしたので、おそらくうっかり触ってしまった、という線で間違いないと思います。いろいろ情報ありがとうございました。